# How can I turn off/set nodmraid for installation?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, dmraid

I've created a live USB to install Ubuntu (on a 4 GB USB).

When I go to install Ubuntu onto my 16GB USB from the live session, I followed some instructions for setting up my partitions then once I finished writing one of the partitions failed or something, then when I tried to redo it a window came up with the Partman crash error.

I read something about pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> on the "initial installation" to turn off dmraid to avoid this problem, but I am not sure what screen to do it on or if I'm even supposed to press <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Can anybody explain in detail how I do this? I've tried pressing <kbd>F6</kbd> immediately after turning on the device but that didn't work. I've tried on my unetbootin screen as my USB is loaded and I've tried spamming the key during installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after initialisation of the Ubuntu installer, two small signs will appear on the bottom of the screen. At this moment you have to press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> button and then extra options will appear such as change the language (<kbd>F2</kbd>) or change installation properties (<kbd>F6</kbd>). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge, the screen in which you can press F6 can only be present when you boot on legacy bios mode. If you boot on UEFI bios mode, this screen will not appear, and you can't press F6 anywhere. But in UEFI mode, you can press `e` to edit options yourself.